# $\frac {|a-b|+|b-a|}{|a|+|b|} = ?$

Tags: absolute-value

$$a<0<b$$

$$\frac {|a-b|+|b-a|}{|a|+|b|} = ?$$

Let me show my thinkings

If $a<0<b$ then $a$ must be negative. If we look at $b$, it must be positive too. However, I still doubt it.

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since we have $$a<0<b$$ and we have $$b-a>0$$ and the term is given by
$$\frac{2|b-a|}{b-a}=\frac{2(b-a)}{b-a}=2$$

Comment: How did you find $b-a$ from $|a| + |b|$?

Comment: we have $$|a|=-a$$ since $a<0$ and $$|b|=b$$ since $$b>0$$

Comment: Got it now! Thanks.

Comment: nice, a nice Christmas and a happy new year

Comment: You too! Doctor.